# Text appear/disappear on top of image with button toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

In mobile, I'm trying to create a toggle that appears on top of an image, that when tapped on, makes text appear on top of the image too.

I basically want to recreate how [The Guardian newspaper](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/jan/11/germany-must-pull-together-to-achieve-climate-targets-says-green-minister) handles the little (i) icon in the bottom right corner on mobile.

And on desktop, the the text is there by default under the image and the (i) icon is gone.

So far I've managed to find a similar solution elsewhere online but it's not quite working right as I need it to.

```js
function toggleText() {
   var text = document.getElementById("demo");
   if (text.style.display === "none") {
      text.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```css
#blog {
    width: 100%;
}

#blog figure {
    position: relative;
}

#blog figure figcaption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#blog figure button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="blog">
  <figure> 
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4635813/marble-around-the-world.jpg" alt="A photo of a slab of marble for example">
    <figcaption id="demo" style='display: none'>A photo of a slab of marble for example</figcaption>
    <button type='button' onclick="toggleText()">(i)</button>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: STOP using inline JS `on*` attribute handlers, same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes (*Edit: wooops you do!*). JS and CSS should be in one place only, and those are the respective files or tags. Use `.addEventListener()` instead and `#demo { display: none; }`.

Comment: I know, I'd like to not do this either, but without that inline style of display: none, I have to click/tap the button twice to make the caption appear, not ideal...

Comment: What you're stating is not true. An inline `display: none;` equals a `display: none;` coming from a CSS file stylesheet. Think about it.

Comment: If you have a go on this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbn3tda8) you'll see what I mean. As it is, **with** an inline style attribute `display:none` clicking on the button makes the figcaption appear (as it should) – `display:none` is in the CSS too. If I remove the inline style attribute of `display:none` and Run the Fiddle again, when I first click on the button, the figcaption doesn't appear, but it does on the second click. I've reRun the Fiddle a few times and this is what happens. I'm not the most knowledgeable developer, but as far as I understand, something has to initialize first...

Comment: In such case instead of checking `el.style.display === "something" ` use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle Or rather just use `el.classList.toggle("someClassName", boolean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use IDs. Your code should be reusable!
- Don't use inline JS `on*` handlers, use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead
- Don't use inline `style` attributes.
- Don't use `el.style.display === "something"` to check for `display` styles. Use [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead

This straightforward example uses JavaScript to simply toggle a className `"is-active"` on the button's parent, the `figure` Element.
Everything else (icon symbol change, caption animation etc...) is handled purely by CSS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("figure button").forEach(EL_btn => {  
  EL_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    EL_btn.closest("figure").classList.toggle("is-active");
  });
});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

img {
  max-width: 100%; /* Never extend images more than available */
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* overflow hidden to allow figcaption hide bottom */
}

figure img {
  display: block; /* prevent "bottom space" caused by inline elements */
}

figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-right: 4rem; /* Prevent text going under the button icon */ 
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(100%); /* Move down, out of view */
  transition: transform 0.3s; /* Add some transition animation */
}

figure.is-active figcaption {
  transform: translateY(0%); /* Move into view */
}

figure button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
figure button::before {
  content: "\2139"; /* i icon */
}

figure.is-active button::before {
  content: "\2A09"; /* x icon */
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4635813/marble-around-the-world.jpg" alt="A photo of a slab of marble for example">
  <figcaption>A photo of a slab of marble for example</figcaption>
  <button type="button"></button>
</figure>
```

The above will work for any number of such elements on your website without the need to add any more CSS or JS.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy!!! I can see this being the better way to do it! Could I ask for your support one last time (I hope!)? I've applied your example to a [test post on my site](https://liamjmoore.com/blog/test-figcaption/) but I'm still running into that figcaption being off, it's not completely at `bottom: 0` from the looks of things. I have style resets (which I think are the culprit) but I've been scratching my head for a few hours now and I can't fix that figcaption being off...

Comment: In fact I can see the same thing happening that code snippet, it's like the figcaption pops up -5px below the image, not at `bottom: 0`

Comment: @liamjmoore that's cause the image is `inline` by default. Use `display: block;` instead. Will fix my demo too.

Comment: So simple – d'oh!!! Thanks again Roko, much much appreciated!

Comment: @liamjmoore you're very welcome! Happy coding ☕

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things that could mess this up, one is the fact that there is nothing to make your image adjust to your mobile screen, more-over there is also margin that is there by default, so I suggest these changes to the CSS:

First I'd set box-sizing to border-box and margin to 0, this should be a regular practice by the way.

```
*{

  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;

}
```

Then select the image and make it adjust to your page as such

```
#blog figure img{
  height: auto;
   width:100%;
}
```

Finally, for some styling you can add some padding to your blog div to make the image slightly smaller on your screen

```
#blog {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 35px;
}
```

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbn3tda8/) for it.

Comment: i notice the caption and the button is slightly lower then the image, might want to add bottom:0 to the caption and button

Comment: @mok_ku the caption and button already have those **edit**: its most likely because of the button border going off the edge pushing some stuff, doing bottom: 4px; for both (which is the thickness of the border) fixes it just right

Comment: Wow thank you lucian! I can see this nearly working now! To mok_ku's point, I see the bottom:0 AND I also removed the border around the button, but I still see the caption and button are still a few pixels below/off the image... Don't suppose anyone would also know how to resolve it so that the text if it's longer (because I've been fiddling trying to find edge cases) DOESN'T go behind the button?

Comment: If it's anything, I've had a go at applying it properly to [my blog](https://liamjmoore.com/blog/change-your-perspective-not-your-job) would love to not nudge that misaligned caption using pixels (as I have done for now), I'm "nervous" it might display incorrectly in other browsers/devices...